# bubble graph with categorical data order by period and divide by type

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder if someone could helpme because I'm try to do the next graph

[image]

but I only have this and I don't know why or what I have to do

[image]

this is my sintaxis

```
base = read.table(text = 
"sex;period;type;count
A;C;E;63
A; D; E;5
B; C; E; 82
B;D;E;50
A;C;F;99
A;D;F;9
B;C;F;121
B; D; F; 22",
                  header = TRUE, sep=";")
attach(base)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(base, aes(x = sex, y = period)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = count), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_size(range = c(0.5, 12)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=count),size=4)
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a possible solution is to facet your plot.

I'm using `dplyr` to pass a pipe sequence to 1) modify your example (there is some extra spaces in "period" and "type" variables and 2) modify "type variable to make the appropriate labeling on the plot.

Using `facet_grid`, you can place two panels one on top of the other and by manipulating `theme` function, you can obtained the desired output:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

base %>% mutate(type = sub(" ","",type), period = sub(" ","",period)) %>%
  mutate(type = paste("Type",type)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = sex, y = period, size = count))+
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5)+
  scale_size(range = c(0.5, 12)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=count),size=4)+
  facet_grid(type~.)+
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        strip.background.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: if there is another numerical column how to map that into the graph?